# Retrieve occurrences of a csv file with strings using Pandas to generate another csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I have an input file that contains the next strings:

```
input_file:

1234
3546
```

and a csv file that contains the next lines:

```
csv_file:

1234|2021-04-20
1234|300087
3546|2019-05-15
3546|300089
8576|2021-08-05
4332|2018-10-04
```

I want to find the strings **1234** and **3546** and return the occurrences of the complete line to place it into another csv file having something like this at the end:

```
output_data_csv:

1234|2021-04-20
1234|300087
3546|2019-05-15
3546|2019-05-15
```

My code is as follow:

```
list_to_find = pd.read_csv(input_file, header=None)
data_to_read = pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep = '|',header=None)                    
output_data_csv = data_to_read[data_to_read[0].isin(list_to_find[0])]
output_data_csv.to_csv('output.csv', index=False, header=None)
```

The result only gives

```
output.csv:

1234|2021-04-20
3546,2019-05-15
```

But I need all the ocurrences

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: you need to join the dataframes on the ID column

Comment: are you sure about the output example? regarding the 3546 last line