# check if column is blank in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the next csv file:

```
A|B|C
1100|8718|2021-11-21
1104|21|
```

I want to create a dataframe that gives me the date output as follows:

```
            A       B                C
0        1100    8718   20211121000000
1        1104      21   ""
```

This means

```
if C is empty:
    put doublequotes
else:
    format date to yyyymmddhhmmss (adding 0s to hhmmss)
```

My code:

```
df['C'] = np.where(df['C'].empty, df['C'].str.replace('', '""'), df['C'] + '000000')
```

but it gives me the next:

```
      A      B            C
0  1100   8718   2021-11-21
1  1104     21            0
```

I have tried another piece of code:

```
if df['C'].empty:
                df['C'] = df['C'].str.replace('', '""')
        else:
                df['C'] = df['C'].str.replace('-', '') + '000000'
```

OUTPUT:

```
      A      B                 C

0  1100   8718    20211121000000
1  1104     21           0000000
```

Comment: Check the documentation on `pandas.Series.empty`. I don't think that's the check you're going for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dt.strftime`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep='|', parse_dates=['C'])
df['C'] = df['C'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S').fillna('""')
print(df)

# Output:
      A     B               C
0  1100  8718  20211121000000
1  1104    21              ""
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I applied the change but it's giving an error: AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
Do you know what can be wrong?

Comment: Do you use `parse_dates` parameter?

Comment: yes I did as you mentioned.

Comment: Try to force the conversion:  `df['C'] = pd.to_datetime(df['C'], errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S').fillna('""')`

Comment: Now it does not give an error but the output is: 
                               0
2021-11-21 00:00:00
                               0

Not as expected :( ... if you know an alternative I'd appreciate it

Comment: It's not possible if you append `.dt.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S').fillna('""')`

Comment: I gave it a rest .. and today I realized that I had a typing mistake .. Finally it worked. Yesterday I was blurred and wasn't thinking clearly .. so thanks a lot.

Comment: @gesgallar. Glad to read that! Did you solve your [previous problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69488551/retrieve-occurrences-of-a-csv-file-with-strings-using-pandas-to-generate-another)?

Comment: Yes I did.. again thankiu very much .. :D

Answer (score 0):

A good way would be to convert the column into datetime using `pd.to_datetime` with parameter `errors='coerce'` then dropping `None` values.

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame({
    'one': 20211121000000,
    'two': 'not true',
    'three': '20211230'
}, index = [1])

x.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce')).T.dropna()

# Output: 

                            1
one   1970-01-01 05:36:51.121
three 2021-12-30 00:00:00.000
```